How do I find the position of a point within a right angle triangle when the angles to the vertices (whose coordinates are known) are known?
I have a right-angle triangle $ABC$ where $\angle B = 90^\circ$, and angles $A$ and $C$ are known along with the lengths of the legs and hypotenuse of the triangle too.
A point $D$ is at an unknown location within the triangle. The angles to points $A$, $B$, and $C$ from $D$ are known. How do I find the coordinates of point $D$? A diagram is attached for better understanding, and any help is appreciated.


I don't know whether this works, but there should be a way to find the circumcircle of a triangle whose base vertices are known and the opposite angle is also known. So, find the circumcircle of $\Delta ABD$ and that of $\Delta BCD$ and find the points where they intersect.

Welcome to Math SE. You can use the Law of sines, plus the $\sin$ sum and difference formulas in Angle sum and difference identities, with just $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$ to get $\tan(\measuredangle ABD)$ and, thus, $\measuredangle ABD$. Using some more trigonometry and algebra will then permit determining the coordinates of $D$.

@JohnOmielan, thank you for your help. If possible could you please elaborate on how to get tan(∡)?

You're welcome. You can get an expression for $j$ from using the law of sines in both $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$, so equate them and then go from there (e.g., expand the $\sin$ values, and do various algebraic manipulations). If you're still having trouble, I suggest you update your question with what you've got so far, as well as where you're stuck.

Note that the algebra and calculations are a bit simpler to determine $\tan(\measuredangle BAD$ instead. I suggested using $\measuredangle ABD$ in my earlier comments as that's the angle that I used when I initially worked on your problem to try to determine a solution method.

Intuitively it admits a brute-force method. WLOG set $B=O$, and $A,C$ on the negative axes. Write $A=(-a,0)$, $C=(0,-c)$, where $a,c>0$. Then the coordinates of $D(x,y)$ has to satisfied
$$\begin{cases}
x\le0\\
y\le0\\
\dfrac{x}{-a}+\dfrac{y}{-c}\le1
\end{cases}$$
The basic idea is

Find a possible coordinate $P_1$ such that $\angle AP_1B$ is the required fixed angle $\varepsilon$.
Find the circumcircle of $\Delta AP_1B$.
Repeat $P_2$ for $\angle BP_2C$ by considering required angle $\zeta$ and also the circumcircle $\Delta AP_2B$.
The intersection points of the circumcircle in the required region are exactly the choices of $D$.

This is because every points $X$ lying on the same circumcircle as $P_1$ will have $\angle AXB=\angle AP_1B$ by angle in same segment. Therefore the intersection point would satisfy both conditions on $\varepsilon$ and $\zeta$.
The last step is to find a possible coordinate $P_i$. This can be done by basic sine law and also trigonometry help.

Example. (Just use your example)
We pick $P_1$ such that $\angle P_1AB=10^\circ$. Then by sine law and trigionometry, we have
$$P_1=\left(\dfrac{\sin(10^\circ)(-a)}{\sin\varepsilon}\cos(180^\circ-(10^\circ+\varepsilon)),\dfrac{\sin(10^\circ)(-a)}{\sin\varepsilon}\sin(180^\circ-(10^\circ+\varepsilon))\right)$$
Simplification gives $P_1=\left(\dfrac{\sin(10^\circ)\cos(75.24^\circ)(-6)}{\sin(94.76^\circ)},\dfrac{\sin(10^\circ)\sin(75.24^\circ)(-6)}{\sin(94.76^\circ)}\right)$.
